# Basic authentication Https SSL Android, loopj library

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, loopj

Никак не могу пройти аутентификацию в HTTPS с использованием loopj Asnctask Http library. Как можно это реализовать и что еще мне нужно добавить в свой код.

Мой код:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    etLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnJoin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnJoin);

    String username = etLogin.getText().toString();
    String password = etLogin.getText().toString();
    final String url = "https://IpAddress:Port/index.php/api/user";
    final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.setBasicAuth(username,password, new AuthScope("IP", Port, AuthScope.ANY_REALM));
    client.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));


    btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                    Log.d("App", "Connected");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    Log.d("App","Upload Failed!");
                    Log.d("App","Error Message: " + error.getMessage());
                    Log.d("App", "Error Cause: " + error.getCause());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

В логах пишет:

09-06 05:20:27.471 1254-1254/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp D/App: Upload Failed!

09-06 05:20:27.471 1254-1254/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp D/App: Error Message: UnknownHostException exception: Unable to resolve host "host5.istv.uz": No address associated with hostname

09-06 05:20:27.471 1254-1254/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp D/App: Error Cause: null

09-06 05:20:27.407 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
09-06 05:20:27.407 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
09-06 05:20:27.415 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:289)
09-06 05:20:27.415 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:464)
09-06 05:20:27.423 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
09-06 05:20:27.427 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
09-06 05:20:27.431 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
09-06 05:20:27.431 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
09-06 05:20:27.443 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
09-06 05:20:27.443 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
09-06 05:20:27.451 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
09-06 05:20:27.455 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
09-06 05:20:27.455 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
09-06 05:20:27.455 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
09-06 05:20:27.459 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
09-06 05:20:27.459 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
09-06 05:20:27.463 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-06 05:20:27.463 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-06 05:20:27.467 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-06 05:20:27.467 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: Unable to resolve host "host.ipadress.uz"

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте куда стучитесь, явно в никуда, адрес `host.ipadress.uz` не ресолвится.

И еще замечание

```
client.setBasicAuth(username,password, new AuthScope("IP", Port, AuthScope.ANY_REALM));
client.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Эти две строчки кода взаимноисключающие.
Либо первое средствами клиента, либо второе вручную.

Comment: Насчет замечание всё понял спасибо, а адрес без проблем  открывает на браузере эмулятора...

Comment: В манифесте доступ в интернет разрешен?

Comment: Да

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: У меня тоже не ресолвится `ping: cannot resolve host5.istv.uz: Unknown host`